# PDO insert query issue inside a For loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, insert

I'm new to PDO and I got stuck with this problem below. Basically, I can't find out what the hell is wrong with my code: The insert query inside my foreach loop is not inserting anything in my database. Maybe I'm not coding the right way. I need my costumers to answer a dynamic form where all the fields are displayed using mysql and I thought that using a foreach loop would be more convenient. Anyway, turned out that it was much difficult than I've expected. Here is my code... (comments and variables are labeled in Portuguese, if those are hard for you to understand, ask me to translate them)

EDIT #1 - Made some changes based on what you guys advices... still not working.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["nome"])):
        try{
            // Começo da validação
            $pdo->beginTransaction();
            // Validação do campo nome
            if ($_POST["nome"] != null):
                $procurarnome=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username");
                $procurarnome->bindValue(":username",$name);
                $procurarnome->execute();
            else:
                die("Houve um erro no sistema, contate um administrador!");
            endif;
            // Validação dos campos dinâmicos
            foreach ($listarpergunta as $pergunta) {
                if ($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"] != null):
                    $resposta=addslashes($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"]);
                    $cadastraresposta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO form_respostas(perguntaid,username,reposta)VALUES(:perguntaid,:username,:resposta)");
                    $cadastraresposta->bindValue(":perguntaid",$pergunta->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $cadastraresposta->bindValue(":username",$name);
                    $cadastraresposta->bindValue(":resposta",$resposta);
                    $cadastraresposta->execute();
                    echo $resposta;
                    echo "<br />";
                else:
                    $pdo->rollBack();
                    die("Preencha todos os campos corretamente!<br />");
                endif;
            }
            // Todos os arquivos foram preenchidos corretamente
            $pdo->commit();
            echo "Obrigado!";
        }
        catch(PDOException $pe){
             //$pdo->rollback();
             die($pe->getMessage());
        }
    else:
?>
```

When I click to submit my form, I get the "Obrigado" message thing, but nothing happens with the db. If I leave any field in blank, it will display me "Preencha todos os campos" (All the fields need to be filled) so I guess that's nothing wrong with that particular part of the code...

Comment: Refrain from all-caps titles (and question text for that matter). Some folks downvote for that.

Comment: Why pass `$name` inside the query and not bind it as well? Also, try the insert query without using quotes for column names.

Comment: Sorry man, this won't happen again, can you help me with the issue?

Comment: I will try that. About the query, I tried that before and I actually changed it to this since it didn't work too.

Comment: Use curly brackets `{ }` instead of colons `:` in if/else construct. DONT use die in transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It's some issues in your code:

Where your `$listarpergunta` variable is initialized?

And change your query:
    `INSERT INTO    form_respostas(perguntaid,username,reposta)VALUES(:perguntaid,:username,:resposta)`

to:

```
INSERT INTO form_respostas(perguntaid,username,reposta) VALUES (:perguntaid,:username,:resposta)
```

(add spaces)

Comment: $listarpergunta works just fine, it's above this part of the code where I use SELECT querys to display the fields. "  // Busca as perguntas referentes ao form ID
   $buscapergunta=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_perguntas WHERE formid=:formid");
   $buscapergunta->bindValue(":formid",$defineid->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $buscapergunta->execute();
   // Prepara a variavel buscapergunta para listagem
   $listarpergunta=$buscapergunta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);"